# how do I create a url rewrite in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a link: `admin/tcpdf/examples/viewContract.inc.php?id=MTE4` and am trying to make a rewrite rule to just: `/contract/`

Would love some assistance with this!

Comment: Have you read https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html ?

Comment: Do you want to internally rewrite or redirect?

Comment: its look like an internal redirect, because there is no domain given.

Comment: Do you already have a .htaccess in `/admin/` directory?

Comment: I do not. The htaccess is just in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?admin/tcpdf/examples/viewContract.inc.php*$ /contact/ [R=301,L]
```

How to handle 404

```
RewriteRule ^/?error404\.php$ - [R=404]
```

Comment: thanks for the help! When i add that to my htaccess file and save it, refresh the site, a link that goes to admin/tcpdf/examples/viewContract.inc.php?id=MTE4 stays that way, it still doesnt change it...why would that be ?

Comment: This worked now but when it changes to /contract/ it says the page cannot be found.

Comment: Well I have answered your question and you have to handle the rest of it. a simple Example: You can use 404 rewrite to handle page-not-found, and then in 404-page you can check current url and include the required pages etc. There are many ways to do it. Or you can solve this problem with more SEO friendly url structures.. This is a different topic.